# How to understand "so much signs" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

Here is a sentence from [Literature, Technology and Modernity, 1860-2000](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lfwq0dZbCAAC&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=not+so+much+signs+whose+referents+have+disappeared+as+mummies.&source=bl&ots=rCJr6opFef&sig=xaKZ2Qt9D0p8CB916d9qDq_znxw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NE6RVLrnNMWvUePbgrgB&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=not%20so%20much%20signs%20whose%20referents%20have%20disappeared%20as%20mummies.&f=false):

> Just as Vickery has been turned into a three-dimensional negative by an electrical storm, the war dead survived, by the industrial light and magic of cinema, as so many shaky on-screen images, **not so much signs whose referents have disappeared as mummies.**

I was wondering whether there is something missing here concerning "so much signs".
Should it be "so much by signs"? Or how to understand the last part?

Comment: It's actually "not so much X as Y". [Related question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53376/not-so-much-as-something-as-something-else)

Answer (score 1):

If we disregard everything that has no relevance to understanding the grammatical construction which you are finding hard to follow, we could rewrite the crucial part of the sentence like this:

> **They were not so much signs as they were mummies**.

Alternatively,

> **They were mummies more than they were signs.**

Answer (score 1):

You are mis-parsing it. The relevant phrase is the complex quantifier "not so much ... as ...".

The clause parses as

> [[not so much] [signs whose referents have disappeared] as [mummies]].

or to paraphrase

> less like signs whose referents have disappeared than like mummies.